# Как можно изменить значение аргументов всех обьектов класса

Tags: python, pygame

Столкнулся с проблемой что мне нужно обработать столкновения игрока с платформами которые лежат в группе. Пытался делать `all_sprites.rect.x =...` но не работает.
Также интересно как можно автоматизировать создание самих платформ, чтобы не делать это в ручную как я :c
Несколько строчек немного ниже  не помогли

```
        if len(hitlist) > 0:
            print(hitlist)
            self.rect.top = player.rect.bottom
```

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True

W = 1024
H = 768

speed = 10

wd = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.jumpspeed = 5
        self.fallspeed = 5
        self.speed = 10
        self.jump = False
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(60,60))
        self.speed = 20
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        pass



player = Player(W // 2, H // 2, 'sprites\cube.png')

class Platforms(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image,):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(200,100))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.x += speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.x -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.y -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.y += speed

        hitlist = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,all_sprites,False)
        if len(hitlist) > 0:
            print(hitlist)
            self.rect.top = player.rect.bottom






platform1 = Platforms(100,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')
platform2 = Platforms(300,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')
platform3 = Platforms(500,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')
platform4 = Platforms(700,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')
platform5 = Platforms(900,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')
platform6 = Platforms(1100,768 - 50,'sprites\platform.png')

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(platform1)
all_sprites.add(platform2)
all_sprites.add(platform3)
all_sprites.add(platform4)
all_sprites.add(platform5)
all_sprites.add(platform6)


def Draw():
    wd.fill((150,150,150))
    wd.blit(player.image,(player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
    all_sprites.draw(wd)
    pygame.display.flip()



while run :
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get() :
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.QUIT()
            sys.quit()
            run = False



    all_sprites.update()
    player.update()
    Draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spritecollide` возвращает список спрайтов из группы, с которыми пересекается спрайт переданный в первом аргументе.

Это означает, что такой проверки `len(hitlist) > 0` не достаточно, ведь может быть, что игрок столкнулся совершенно с другой платформой, а вы будете двигать текущую. (Это тоже кстати странно, логичнее двигать игрока, но это ваша игра и вам виднее какие у нее правила. У вас получается, что игрок при прыжке сможет двигать платформы вниз).

Проверять нужно, что игрок столкнулся именно с этой платформой, т.е. что она есть в `hitlist`:

```
if self in hitlist:
   self.rect.top = player.rect.bottom
```

Что касается создания платформ, то можно создавать их в цикле, и не повторять то, что одинаковое у всех:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for xpos in [100, 300, 500, 700, 900, 1100]:
   all_sprites.add(Platforms(xpos, 768-50, 'sprites\platform.png')
```

Comment: По поводу движения платформ, так я не знал как бы сделать камеру, и чтобы когда он двигался он не останавливался на границе экрана, а как бы  карта  будто грузилась дальше. И по поводу того что будет сдвигаться одна платформа при столкновении, я вроде написал что будут двигаться все, и получится такая иллюзия, хотя может быть в коде совсем другое.
А все что вы написали совершенно верно, спасибо.

Comment: И если можно, обьясните пожалуйста, как мне двигать самого персонажа, при этом чтобы карта была больше размера экрана, и с движением персонажа в ту сторону, она показывалась, а противоположная сторона исчезала(как это обычно в платформерах как террария и прочее)

Comment: Это лучше задать отдельный вопрос, ответ будет длинным :) Если коротко, то посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357169/2231972